# Show everything before a match

Tags: ruby

I have a regex to find TV series files on my drive

```
if (filename =~ /S\d+?E\d+?/ix)
  puts "EPISODE : #{filename}"
```

works well enough and prints the filename which is something like this for example

```
EPISODE : Lie.to.Me.S02E02.Truth.or.Consequences.HDTV.XviD-2HD.avi
```

How can I display everything before the match, instead of the whole filename?
So I want to match on the S02E02 but display Lie.to.Me, but this Lie.to.Me string can really be anything, so I cannot do a regex for something specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
s = "Lie.to.Me.S02E02.Truth.or.Consequences.HDTV.XviD-2HD.avi"
m = s.match(/S\d+?E\d+?/ix)
puts m.pre_match
=> "Lie.to.Me."
```

Comment: Or this, even :)  You posted while I was answering.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `` $` `` special variable:

```ruby
def check(filename)
  if (filename =~ /S\d+?E\d+?/ix)
    puts "MATCH: #{filename}" 
    puts "PRE: #{$`}"
  end
end
check 'EPISODE : Lie.to.Me.S02E02.Truth.or.Consequences.HDTV.XviD-2HD.avi'
# MATCH: EPISODE : Lie.to.Me.S02E02.Truth.or.Consequences.HDTV.XviD-2HD.avi
# PRE: EPISODE : Lie.to.Me.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `#match` with a `.*` before your pattern, with a capturing group.

```
"Lie.To.Me-S02E01-Xvid.avi".match(/\A(.*?)S\d+E\d+?/ix)[1]
# => Lie.To.Me-
```

Answer (score 0):

Use pre_match:

```
match = /S\d+?E\d+?/ix.match(filename)
if match then
  puts match.pre_match
end
```

Answer (score 0):

you should look after using parentheses in your regular expression to be able to handle groups:
if (filename =~ /.+(S\d+?E\d+?).*/ix)
  puts "EPISODE : \1" 
That means only the first group that matches will be displayed.